# Chrome change the input Placeholder

Tags: css, google-chrome, placeholder

When I write "email" in the label text or in input id, or in input name, Chrome change the placeholder and it write: "Enter your email here"

```
<label for="email">* Email</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Any Text" name="email" id="email" required>
```

Instead write: "Any text", Chrome write "Enter your email here"

If I change the word "email", Chrome works:

```
<label for="aaa">* aaa</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Any Text" name="aaa" id="aaa" required>
```

I has been searching many time but I don't found the answer to solve it.

Thnaks!
Javier.

Comment: Which version? seems fine to me on 29

Comment: I think you miss something else or any js/jquery doing this thing. I have checked in chrome http://jsfiddle.net/JqA8P/ and its working.